# Can I check or the condition for the slideDown and slideUp when I'm using the slideToggle method?

Tags: jquery, arrays

This is my code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".globe").click(function(){
       $(".language").slideToggle(function(){
         if($(".language").slideDown()){
             // do something
           }else{
            //dosomething
            }
   });
});
```

I have search a lot but getting no result.. please help or provide some alternative to solve this..

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
is(":hidden")
```

function of the jquery.
True - means element is SlidedUp
False - means element is SlidedDown

So your check will be:

```
    if($(".language").is(":hidden")){
         // element is SlidedUp
         // do something
       }else{
         // element is SlidedDown
        //dosomething
        }
```

Comment: This is not working bro... plz provide some other alternative

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this code help you : 
CSS :

```
div{background-color:#000;color:#FFF;padding:5px;margin:3px;}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="d">Slide UP</div>
<div class="fd">Fade Out</div>
<p>rgergeerggereggeeregrgregrgre<br/>rgergeerggereggeeregrgregrgre<br/>rgergeerggereggeeregrgregrgre<br/>
    rgergeerggereggeeregrgregrgre<br/>rgergeerggereggeeregrgregrgre</p><h1> Extra paragraph text</h1>
```

JS Code : slideUp/slideIn Example

```
$('.d').click( function(){
    if($('p').is(":visible")){
        $('p').slideUp(800);
        setTimeout(function() { $('.d').text('Slide Down'); },900);
    }else{
        $('p').slideDown(800);
        setTimeout(function() { $('.d').text('Slide Up'); }, 900);
    }   
});
```

JS Code : fadeIn/fadeOut Example

```
$('.fd').click( function(){
    if($('p').is(":visible")){
        $('p').fadeOut(800);
        setTimeout(function() { $('.fd').text('Fade Out'); },900);
    }else{
        $('p').fadeIn(800);
        setTimeout(function() { $('.fd').text('Fade In'); }, 900);
    }   
});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sunnysm/4r58gjrb/1/) example here